# Swift 2 version of returning optional variables?

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to implement getters/setters for properties. In the computed property, I'm returning the `_locationManager`, but also initializing the first time only:

```
var _locationManager: CLLocationManager? { get set }

var locationManager: CLLocationManager {
    if let manager = _locationManager {
        return manager
    }

    _locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    return _locationManager!
}
```

Is there a more Swift-like version of the above statement? For example, in `C#` I can do something like this:

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager {
    return _locationManager ?? (_locationManager = CLLocationManager())
}
```

This is saying return `_locationManager`, or initialize plus return it. Does Swift have some kind of shorthand or another way for this scenario?

**Update:**

Below is another version. I'm trying to stick with a computed property so it can be used in protocol extensions and/or able to wire up a delegate in the process etc:

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager {
    return _locationManager ?? {
        self._locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        return self._locationManager!
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really desperate to, you can do something like you're asking, but it's not terribly pretty. However, in the example you quoted, you should use lazy instantiation as Palle answered.

```
class Test {
}
var _test: Test?
var test: Test {
    get {
        return _test ?? { _test = Test() ; return _test! }()
    }
}
```

Declaring a closure like this gets you the 'cute' one line getter, but I would leave it as you've got it because it's clearer.

Comment: Take in account, that OP requests it should be initialised the first time only, not when first used. computed property is get only, so his approach mimics more let than lazy var. At first sight the right solution is declare test as let test = Test() and it will works as expected, except in scenario like delegation pattern (he wrote about this in his update). by his approach you still can set the underlying _test to something else later. there is no enough information in the question to see what is the 'best' approach for him, probably what he is doing could be the 'best'

Answer (score 1):

you could use a lazy property for this:

```
lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

a lazy property gets initialized only when it is first used.

Comment: That is cool but unfortunately doesn't work for protocol extensions.

Comment: I believe a location manager should not be created inside a protocol extension but in the implementation of a protocol in a class as this is an implementation specific detail.

Comment: It depends if stored properties are excluded from protocol extensions intentionally or it's on the roadmap. If it's on the roadmap, I'm trying to find a good alternative in the meantime.

Comment: take in account, that OP requests it should be initialised the first time only, not when first used.